# Nativescript hide toolbar on list scroll - Keep tabs

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am creating a Nativescript application ([nativescript-angular](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-angular) `v7.2.2`) with Angular (`v7.2.10`). I am trying to create a native parallax animation to hide the toolbar when scrolling down and show it again when scrolling up.

To better explain what I want, below is the behavior described by Material design: 
[image: Material scroll]

---

**Default behavior**

By default Nativescript [does not implement such animations](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/4908). It is just a static toolbar and tabs ([see this example](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=tJuOve)).

---

**What I want**

That brings me to what I want to achieve, is there a way in Typescript to implement the effect above? I know of a one NativeScript parallax library, [nativescript-parallax](https://github.com/JoshDSommer/nativescript-parallax), but I don't really understand how this fixes my problem or how I should implement it.

There is also the [custom implementation](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=b9hyJh&v=2), but that doesn't make much sense to me. What is the best way I could update my example and implement such behavior? Since I don't think NativeScript is going to support it anytime soon.

Comment: What you see in the attachment is `CoordinatorLayout` which is not implemented in {N} yet, you already seen the Github feature request. The parallax example might work if you use a complete custom view instead of default ActionBar (Toolbar).